# Where are my files created by my Ubuntu Touch apps?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I wrote a note in the Notes app. Looking in my Home directory I can't see it anywhere. How can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything must be under the home directory.

In the note example, all the data are under

```
.local/share/com.ubuntu.reminders/
```

Comment: In the folder is in my case a @local folder that contains the files

Comment: Great, thanks! Of course `ls` doesn't show dotdirectories.

Comment: @Joe exactly, `ls -A` is a better solution :)

Comment: Yep, I didn't think to check. Thanks for your help.